# SSRS - How to group tablix with data one below each other?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a tablix with grouping on three values but all values are in one row.

[image]

But I Want the value to be below each other, structured like this:

[image]

I don't usually group data like that in other reports so it's a bit of a puzzle to me...any help is appreciated!

Comment: Choose to add a header when creating the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfgang is correct. Create your table and add your columns. Then add your Question Group and Question columns as Groups ensuring you tick the 'Add Group Header' checkbox. This will create 2 new header columns on the left of the table. Then delete the original Question Group and Question columns. This should give you the format you require:

[image]

Thanks
Rob